# How can I limit Python class instance method calls to one at a time?

Tags: python

I have a situation where parallel threads sometimes try to operate on the same instance of a class (same object) at the same time, and that causes hardware collision issues. I'm running Python 3.7. I want to configure the class so that if any one method is in the middle of executing, then other parallel method calls to that same instance (any method) automatically wait their turn. Is that possible in Python? In the Labview programming language, that is a convenient option called action-engine VI reentrancy mode. I know that I could add semaphore acquire-release lines of code to all the calls in all the calling threads, but that would be a big ugly bloat compared to a single setting in the class.

Comment: If the dupe doesn't solve your problems, feel free to write a comment and we'll re-open the issue. But it feels like that's a spot on solution for you :)